# What's the preferred way to set values for select dropdowns?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a select dropdown and I'm wondering about what the best convention is to use when setting the values of the child options.

Here's my form field:

```
  <div class="field">
    <label for id="schedule_type">Schedule Type</label><br>
    <select name="schedule_type" id="schedule_type">
      <option value="recurring">Recurring — Create a series of sessions</option>
      <option value="nonrecurring">Not recurring — Create just one session</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Notice I've used the value `"recurring"` and `"nonrecurring"`. I've seen examples use integers as well:

```
<option value="1">Recurring — Create a series of sessions</option>
<option value="2">Not recurring — Create just one session</option>
```

I am being pedantic? Is there no advantage of one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from larger *[non-trivial]* page size (the value `1` vs `recurring`, there's a minuscule difference in byte that can affect page rendering), there's nothing to problem in the front-end. Though this *[might]* affect the back-end.

---

Consider this (back-end agnostic):

1. I pass the value `recurring` on `form.submit` to the server for
   processing.
2. Before saving, the server will first query what is the `id` of the actual schedule type (that is if it is a foreign key)
3. Then save.

Against to passing the actual `id` to the server on save:

1. I pass the value `1` on `form.submit` to the server for
   processing.
2. Then save.

The second one will be faster compared to the first one.

---

But again, depending on the scenario and the design on your back-end, one can be optimal over the other, or it can be negligible at all.